# ASP.NET: Repeater control inside a Gridview row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I want a Repeater control inside a Gridview row. So how can I assign the DataSource of the Repeater control so that the data it uses is that of the specific data of the GridView row?

I tried this:
DataSource='<%# Eval(Container, "DataItem.InnerVal")

but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to handle the [`GridView.RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event in your code-behind.  This will allow you to dynamically create a `Repeater` and bind it to the data for the row you are on.

Answer (score -1):

go through this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/repeater_in_gridview.aspx
Hope it help you.

Comment: Generally people check search engines prior to asking for help. People are capable of using google, they come here for assistance if that fails. Please post answers not links to someone elses answers.